# List issue with verifying index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to make a program that will receive 20 numbers (1 to 10) from the user and put them in a list. Afterwards the user types in a number; it should print how many times the number the user typed appears and the index of such numbers.
I have tried but can't find a solution.

```
x = []
for i in range(0, 21):
    x.append(int(input("Introduza numeros: ")))
y = int(input("Escreva um numero: "))
r = x.index(y)
if r == True:
    print(r)
else:
    print("Não ha esse numero")
```

Answer (score 3):

To get number of times number appears in list use:

```
x.count(y)
```

And to get indices of appearances use:

```
[i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == y]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html explains that index returns the 0 based index of the first occurrence of the value.  If you want to count the occurrences of a value, use `count ()` instead.

```
r = x. count(y)
if r > 0:
    print(r)
else:
    print("Não ha esse numero")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 21):
    x.append(int(input("Introduza numeros: ")))
y = int(input("Escreva um numero: "))
r = [indx for indx, num in enumerate(x) if num == y]
if r == True:
    print(len(r))    
    print(r)
else:
    print("Não ha esse numero")
```

I used List comprehension to iterate through the list and enumerate to find the index.

Answer (score 0):

Although Zipa's answer is pretty much the best , if you want another method for this `count` operation then you can try this:

def count(x,list_):
        return len([i for i in list_ if i == x])

```
>>> count(2,[2,3,2,5])
>>> 2
```

> NOTE:
>   This method is slower than `x.count` as it involves array generation and
>   counting and I am sure `x.count()` must be using some very optimized algorithm in comparison to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list you could **use a dictionary** to store numbers with each **unique user entry as a key** and **it's count as value**.

```
user_entries = dict()
for i in range(0, 21):
    entry = int(input("Introduza numeros: "))
    if entry not in user_entries:
        user_entries[entry] = 1  # Creating new entry for new numbers
    else:
        user_entries[entry] += 1  # Updating old entries' count
y = int(input("Escreva um numero: "))
if y in user_entries:
    print(user_entries[y])  # Printing count of existing entry
else:
    print("Não ha esse numero")
```